# Чат на node.js как плагин для CMS

Tags: node.js, чат

Нам часто стили клиенты писать, что очень не хватает модуля, что того, что бы дать возможность пользователям сайта, или каких-то разделов сайта общаться в реальном времени, т.е. чата.

У многих наших клиентов, посещаемость около 300 000 пользователей в день.
Реализация чата на ajax отпадает.

в поле зрения попадает node js и вебсокеты.

Проблема в том, что наши плагины устанавливаются через CMS, пользователь их качает, устанавливает и готово.
Установка происходит естественно на php.

Т.е. не представляю как реализовать чат, с javascript на стороне сервера, ведь у клиентов сайт на php. И предлагать им устанавливать node, переделавать сайт и т.д. - не вариант. люди хотят скачать, установить, и работать.

Господа, какие вы видите решения? какие есть способы? реализации чата на вебсокетах, что бы клиенту не нужно было никаких плясок с бубном вокруг хостинга?

Comment: Развернуть [мультиарендную](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) реализацию на собственных мощностях и брать с клиентов деньги за пользование?

Comment: Спасибо. А в чем минусы реализовать это на неблокирующих сокетах php и websocket ?

Comment: Именно это неплохо рассказывается в уже опубликованном ответе. И мне не очень понятно, с какой целью вы оставили идентичный комментарий и к нему.

Answer (score 1):

> Реализация чата на ajax отпадает.

Вы имели ввиду технологию long-polling? Ну при больших нагрузках сокеты действительно будут экономичнее.

На PHP тоже есть возможность развернуть полноценный веб-сокет сервер в виде демона и для этого тьма библиотек на github.

Вас больше должны волновать проблемы связанные с связанные с хостингом, потому что веб-сокет сервер вешается на порт, а на **обычном хостинге** тысячи клиентов на одном сервере и IP и вероятно, что у многих просто не будет прав, чтобы включить веб-сокет сервер.

Предположим, что у кого-то был VPS или собственный сервер, теперь очень желательно, чтобы веб-сокет сервер был прописан в демоне, который бы мог следить и управлять им в случае падения или перезагрузки, например в **systemd** или **supervisor**.

В общем, без доступа в командную строку веб-сокет сервер не развернуть корректно, но я не вижу проблем написать модуль и к нему инструкцию по запуску и корректному мониторингу.

Comment: Спасибо. А в чем минусы реализовать это на неблокирующих сокетах php и websocket ?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого Вам потребуется поднимать и поддерживать собственные IM-сервера (написанные на Node JS), к которым будут обращаться ваши клиенты.

Делаете клиентскую часть с WebSockets на JavaScript. Она общается напрямую с одним из ваших IM-серверов, что обеспечивает получение данных в режиме реального времени. Параллельно запросы в базу данных отправляются традиционным AJAX-запросом в PHP.

То есть, Instant Messaging мы реализовываем полностью на Node JS, а отправку данных в базу через PHP.